# Obtaining the coordinates of an objects vertices, without the objects scale and rotations applied

Tags: python, scripting, export, vertices, vector

I have constructed a tileset for a project and need to exporting the vertices of each object.

[image: The Tileset]

When I take the position of all of the vertices of an object it applies the scale and rotation factors I used when making the objects. Every tile is in its correct rotation and scale as I would like them but still have values in these fields.

[image: Exporting the coords]

Any idea how to export the vertices before these transformations are applied?

Comment: The code you have is obtaining the coords before any object transform is applied.